# Android: How to get my MapView's Screen coordinates (the visible region)?

Tags: android

I want to get coordinates from set pixel from mapView.

In this code I get coordinates, but  it's for the next region:

```
mapView.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(point);
```

Comment: duplicate of [How can l get coordinates from set point from mapView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862456/how-can-l-get-coordinates-from-set-point-from-mapview-in-android) If you can't get an answer for your question, improve it instead of duplicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider use Google maps api v2 and use a fragment instead a simple mapview The info that you need is here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource

I hope that it can help you

Comment: l use this in my .xml <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />